# How to split a string into multiple variables & if not enough values, assign the variable as a particular value?

Tags: python, variables, split

I have this code (Python 3.9):

```
vdam = {"mirror": 0, "door": 1, "windShield": 2}
vdam2 = list(vdam.items())
vdam3 = [a[0] for a in vdam2]
vdam4 = ' '.join([str(ele) for ele in vdam3])
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = vdam4.split()
```

I want to split the string into multiple variables but at the same time, if not enough values to be split, all other left variables get assigned as a particular value.
The above code generates the error like this:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 7, got 3)
```

Comment: Why? If the number of elements varies dynamically, you should use a list.

Comment: I want to separate into multiple variables because it will verify each of them to get another value from a dictionary.

Comment: Unrelated: `list(vdam.keys())` directly gets you the result of `vdam4.split()`.  No need for vdam2-vdam4 and the .split().

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am using ```vdam3``` somewhere else too, that's why it is converting that way. Thanks for telling.

Comment: `vdam3` is just `list(vdam.keys())`.  Why join them with spaces then split again?  It's just unnecessary code for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Append default values to the list to make it contain the number of elements equal to the number of variables. Then assign them.

```
vdam5 = vdam4.split()
if len(vdam5) < 7:
    vdam5 += [None] * (7 - len(vdam5))
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = vdam5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion (updated based on a comment from Blckknght)

```
def fit(mystring, expected_length, replacement_value):
    while len(mystring)<expected_length:
        mystring +=replacement_value
    return mystring

vdam = {"mirror": 0, "door": 1, "windShield": 2}
vdam2 = list(vdam.items())
vdam3 = [a[0] for a in vdam2]
vdam4 = ' '.join([str(ele) for ele in vdam3])
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = fit(vdam4.split(),7,'A')
```

```
mirror door windShield A A A A
```

Comment: Why not `def fit(string, expected_length, replacement_value)`? There's no good reason to use single letter names and then need to document them with comments.

Comment: Thanks, @Blckknght, I updated the code as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

`vdam2-vdam4` are not needed, nor the `.split()`.  List the keys and append enough defaults to handle 0-7 arguments.  The final `*_` captures the excess items:

```
>>> vdam = {"mirror": 0, "door": 1, "windShield": 2}
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,*_ = list(vdam.keys()) + [None]*7
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g
('mirror', 'door', 'windShield', None, None, None, None)
```

If you have varying defaults, this works by expanding the keys as parameters to the function:

```py
>>> vdam = {"mirror": 0, "door": 1, "windShield": 2}
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,*_ = list(vdam.keys()) + [None]*7
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g
('mirror', 'door', 'windShield', None, None, None, None)

>>> def func(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7):
...    return a,b,c,d,e,f,g
...
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g = func(*vdam.keys())
>>> print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
mirror door windShield 4 5 6 7
```

Note you could also use `func(*vdam4.split())` as well if you have a space-delimited string.